# Компилятор, Исходный код, Java классы, Java файлы

Tags: java, терминология, jvm

Правильно ли я понял?

На языке программирования Java весь исходный код сначала написан в текстовых файлах, заканчивающихся расширением `.java`.

Потом эти исходные файлы компилируются в `.class`-файлы компилятором `javac`. Но файл `.class` не содержит кода, он содержит байт-код машинный язык Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

Затем инструмент запуска java запускает ваше приложение с экземпляром виртуальной машины Java. (вот это не понял).

Comment: `java` запускает виртуальную машину, которая загружает class-файл и выполняет его. Что именно вам непонятно?

Comment: Сначала мы пишем исходный код который написан в текстовых файла у которых расширение .java. Потому эти файлы компилируются в файлы с расширением .class компилятором. А файлы с расширение .class не содержат кода, а содержат байт код верно? А потом что происходит с этим байт кодом? Я правильно описал как код в байт код "переходит"?

Comment: Верно. Потом этот байткод считывается виртуальной машиной байт за байтом и выполняется, как я уже написал.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev спасибо большое, а то с документации не так перевёл, хотел узнать точный правильный вариант

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev проверьте ответ ниже, он некорректен я думаю, JDK средства компиляции, а не запуска же

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван это не мой ответ, я не стану его править. На сколько он правильный, вы можете оценить сами, почитав про [JDK](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) и [JRE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Runtime_Environment) в википедии например.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Извиняюсь тогда, просто думал вы модератор.

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван у модераторов ромбик ♦ рядом с именем. Но они тоже не занимаются оценкой правильности ответов.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а кто мониторит правильность ответов?  Я просто вижу тут человек недавно и могу сделать вывод что он только начал изучать этот яп и ему показался этот ответ правильным, хотя на самом деле тут некорректен ответ, тогда как проверяют правильность ответов?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван автор вопроса оценивает правильность отметкой о решении, а сообщество оценивает голосами.

Answer (score 1):

Инструмент запуска Java - это JDK. Он содержит JRE, которая запускается процессом java. Этот процесс запускает JVM, которая читает и выполняет ваши файлы.

Виртуальная машина JVM содержит виртуальный процессор, который выполняет байт-код. А также содержит JIT компилятор, который транслирует байт-код в машинный код. Этот код и выполняется на вашем компе.

Comment: Это понятно, для того чтобы получить галочку, вам скорей всего надо расписать полностью процесс, аля: Сначала мы пишем исходный код который написан в текстовых файла у которых расширение .java. Потому эти файлы компилируются в файлы с расширением .class компилятором. А файлы с расширение .class не содержат кода, а содержат байт код и тд

Comment: Я ответил только на то что вы не поняли, остальное вы уже дополнили комментариями.

Comment: Благодарю вас :)

Comment: JDK - это средства компиляции, а не запуска. Для запуска как раз JRE - среда выполнения.

Comment: @Hive JDK содержит в себе JRE, чтоб тебе было понятно.