# Настройка текстового редактора для компиляции кода

Tags: java, компиляция, notepad++

Решил удариться в хардкод использовав обычный текстовый редактор notepad++, но возникла загвоздка в его настройке.

Кто может описать шаги для настройки блокнота ?

Возьмем по классике, первую программу программиста "Hello world", написал, как компилировать ?

```
class Hello_Word {

    public static void main (String args []) {

        System.out.println("Hello World");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Будет трудно поставить jvm на калькулятор, не в ладах с прошивкой

Comment: См https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/901836/204920

Comment: @RomanC лучше тогда сразу ссылку на [Вики](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) кинул бы

Comment: [Первая же ссылка](https://geekbrains.ru/posts/npp_java) в Google по запросу "notepad++ java". Но лучше просто писать код в редакторе, а компилировать и запускать в отрытом рядом окне консоли.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev из этого отличный ответ мог бы получиться)